# Make text viewer read files faster in android

Tags: java, android, string, text, bufferedreader

I have a simple text viewer class that opens text file and reads the strings. But the problem is, when the file is large >0.5Mb, opening takes quite a while. Is there a way to load small part first and then load all others or any other way to make this process faster ? Here is my code:

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
    String str = "";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    try {
        inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    if (inputStream!=null) {
        try {
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buf.append(str + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        txt.setText(buf.toString());
    }
    }
```

Comment: tried using txt.append() ?

Comment: no, how can I do that ?

Comment: By adding your data in chunks

Comment: post code snippet pls

Comment: I mean, can you pls modify mine ? Or create one, so I can see how to do this ?